# How to count frequency of an enum in an ArrayList of object

Tags: java, collections, enums

As an example to my question... Say I have an `ArrayList` containing `Car` objects. A `Car` object is comprised of a `Model` and `Colour` `Enum`. I want to count how many car models of type Audi are in the list, Audi is an `ENUM`

I have an int variable called int Audi

And I'm trying `Audi=Collections.frequency(list, Model.AUDI);`

However it is not counting the frequency and `Audi=0`

Where am I going wrong and how can I count the frequency of an enum?

Comment: Please show the source code for your `Car` class.

Comment: Your `list` is not list of models, but of cars. When looping `frequency` compares found `car` with `model` you passed ans since no car is equal to model you are getting `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `Collections.frequency` is incorrect; you are looking in a list of `Car`s for a `Model` enum, so it's no surprise that the count is 0.

If you're using Java 8, you can set up a `Stream` so that you can `filter` the contents and then `count` the remaining elements.  This assumes that `Car` has a `getModel` getter method.

```
long audi = list.stream().filter( c -> c.getModel() == Model.AUDI ).count();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Collections.frequency` only works if the array is containing objects of the same Type as the object passed.  In this case, you have an array of type `<Car>` and are checking for an object of type `Model` (an instance of Car will never equal an enum Model).

You will need to write your own loop to go through and perform the count (it should be easy).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach(java8 required) is to first groupBy(in your case groupBy self) which will return `Map<Car, List<Car>>`, passing `Collectors.counting()` will return Map

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

//guava & pseudocode
List<Car> listOfCars = Lists.newArrayList(Car.AUDI, Car.BMW, Car.AUDI, Car.AUDI, Car.BMW);

listOfCars.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), 
                Collectors.counting()));
```